# Redmine on openshift: how to install subversion client

Tags: svn, openshift, redmine

I have a redmine instance running on openshift, but I am a relative noob when it comes to linux and git. Redmine has repository tracking built in and supports most major version management systems. I use a subversion repository (hosted elewhere) and changing to git is not really an option for reasons I won't go into here. I cannot connect my redmine to the repository as the svn command is not available on the openshift server. I know I just need some basic subversion client package installed but I have no idea how to set it up. Could anyone tell me what the commands are to achieve this? I basically just need the svn command to be supported I do not need a repo set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post getting svn client installed to https://www.openshift.com/ideas and email open shift@redhat.com (ATTN Corey in the subject line) and I'll ask ops about getting it installed.

You might also be able to download the source (or a binary distribution) of svn to your OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR on your gear and run it from there while I check on getting it installed on the nodes.

Comment: Great, I'll ping ops about it on Monday

Comment: There is currently a pull request to get subversion installed here: https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/pull/5476

Comment: The SVN client executable is now available on the servers.